# When does the base of the image is directly comprized of the columns of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused with what methods and when to use them to find the base of the image of  a matrix.

1. Sometimes I see that they use gauss-jordan to find which columns have pivots and then they take the columns from the original matrix to make the base.
2. Other times, I see them taking the columns directly from the matrix to make the base.
3. Lastly  they write the matrix in form of linear combinations of simpler matrices and use those simpler matrices to make the base. i.e: $A = (a_0 a_1 a_2) = a_0(1 0 0 0) + a_1(0 1 1 0) + a_2(0 0 0 2)$ and then $I_m(A)= {(1 0 0 0), (0 1 1 0), (0 0 0 2)}$.

So when do you use each of those method?
Update*** I am particularly interested in knowing when the image of matrix isn't comprized of all the columns of that matrix. This when you have to use Gauss-Jordan to see which columns contains the pivots so you can select the columns from the original matrix to constitute your basis. **How to identify when it is this method that you have to use as opposed to just taking every column and put it in the basis?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns of a matrix aren't linearly independent, then they cannot comprise a basis. Otherwise, they do, though other bases may be more convenient to work with for various reasons.

To see why the columns of a matrix span the image, suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and that $\vec x$ is an $n\times 1$ vector (with appropriate entries). Observe that $$\vec x=x_1\vec{e_1}+\cdots+x_n\vec{e_n},$$ where $\vec{e_j}$ is the $n\times 1$ matrix with $1$ in the $j$th entry and $0$ in the others. Further observe that $A\vec{e_j}$ is the $j$th column of $a$ (say $\vec{a_j}$) for each $1\le j\le n.$ Consequently,

\begin{eqnarray}A\vec x &=& A\left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\vec{e_j}\right)\\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^nA\left(x_j\vec{e_j}\right)\\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^nx_j\left(A\vec{e_j}\right)\\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^nx_j\vec{a_j},\end{eqnarray}

meaning that the elements of the image are linear combinations of the columns of $A,$ and so comprise a basis if and only if the columns are linearly independent.

Comment: I am particularly interested in knowing when the image of matrix isn't comprized of all the columns of that matrix. This when you have to use Gauss-Jordan to see which columns contains the pivots so you can select the columns from the original matrix to constitute your basis. How to identify when it is this method that you have to use as opposed to just taking every column and put it in the basis?